# unable to display the returned value from a cursor using meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a template that looks like this:

```
<template name="item_list">
    {{#each items}}
        <div>{{name}}</div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

This template has some client js code:

```
Template.item_list.helpers(
{
items: function() // find items
    {
        Meteor.call('getId', Meteor.userId(), function(error, result)
        {
            if(error)
            {
                console.log(error.message);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(result); // correct id returned

                Meteor.call('findItemById', result, function(error, result)
                {
                    if(error)
                    {
                        console.log(error.message);
                        console.log(error.stack);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log(result); // this contains 2 objects with the correct values

                        return result;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

When I log result I get the correct objects in the console but my template is still empty. The column "name" does exist in the objects returned. Like this:

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
_id: "Mcqf3Hh2ARH2NJsDB"
name: "item 1"

1: Object
_id: "e9mkxgNqHgM3czMvE"
name: "item 2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep in mind javascript is asynchronous. When you use 'return' in a callback, it wont return to the original Method call. It'll just return to the callback method.

You have to interface the data using a `Session` variable and run the initial call the template is created.

```
Template.item_list.helpers(
{
    items: function() {
        return Session.get('items');
    }
});

Template.item_list.created = function() {

    Meteor.call(... function(err,result) {
    ....
      Session.set('items', result);
    ....

    }

}
```